# xcode framework per configuration

Tags: xcode, build, configuration, frameworks

I have two versions of a framework: (1) to be use for debug builds and (2) the other to be used for release/production builds. If I add the framework to the "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" area under the General tab everything links fine. However this location doesn't allow me to choose per configuration. The Build Settings "Framework Search Paths" and "Library Search Paths" allow for this.

However if I set these paths and remove the framework from the "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" area the linking fails.

How can I accomplish a per configuration framework linking? Currently using Xcode 13.2.1 (not the latest but that is a different story.) The app is a SwiftUI app in case that matters.

Comment: Is it a 3rd party framework, or internal? The easiest solution is a XCFramework that includes both debug and release.

Comment: A package might help too

Comment: Its an internal xcframework. One is built with debugging code, the other isn't. Thus I need my app to choose which one to use based on the configuration. I have no access to how those xcframeworks are generated/built.

Comment: How does one take two already made binary xcframeworks and create one with debug and release versions? I could not find any way to do this.